# $Lookup inside an array with more properties MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying `$lookup` in Array but can't merge it in my object after `$lookup`.

Collection

```
_id: '5f7a1053477c8a1ae88e22cf',
name: 'Demo'
price: 423,
related: [
 {
  idProduct: '61140763ab806726a8ab7aea'
  quantity: 2
 },
 {
  idProduct: '61140763ab806726a8ab7aeb'
  quantity: 6
 },
]
```

Expected Output:

```
_id: '5f7a1053477c8a1ae88e22cf',
name: 'Demo',
price: 423,
related: [
      {
        idProduct: {
          _id: '61140763ab806726a8ab7aea',
          name: 'related1',
          price: 22
        },
        quantity: 2
      },
      {
        idProduct: {
          _id: '61140763ab806726a8ab7aeb',
          name: 'related2',
          price: 53
        },
        quantity: 6
      },
   ]
```

I need `$lookup`, `idProduct` and keep that data structure.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `related` array
- `$lookup` with collection 2, pass `related.idProduct` as local field and `_id` as foreign field and set in `related.idProduct`
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `related` array and get first required firlds

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$related" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "related.idProduct",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "related.idProduct"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      price: { $first: "$price" },
      related: { $push: "$related" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Q8hsThhfNG)

---

The second approach without using `$unwind` stage,

- `$lookup` with collection 2,
- `$map` to iterate loop of `related` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `col2` array by `idProduct` field
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above filtered result
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `idProduct` field

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "related.idProduct",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "col2"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      col2: "$$REMOVE",
      related: {
        $map: {
          input: "$related",
          as: "r",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$r",
              {
                idProduct: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$col2",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$r.idProduct", "$$this._id"] }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBIvby6qAoL)